# Passing the right argument to strtok

Tags: c, string, strtok

I have this string that I'm trying to delimit with `strtok()`:

> "+ 2 3\\nln 9\\ln 10"

And then I'm passing `\\n` as a delimiter

```
    token = strtok(argv, "\\n");

    while (token)
    {
            args[index] = token;
            token = strtok(NULL, "\\n");
            index++;
    }
```

First element in my `args` table is `+ 2 3` ,which is great, however, the second one is `l`.
Does anyone understand why ? If so, how do I get my `ln 9` in my `args` table?

Comment: The last argument is a list of characters that can act as delimiters.  So `"\\n"` means you want to split it any time you find a backslash or an n

Comment: sorry I edited the string, it came out differently than expected. I want to split any time there is an occurrence of \\n, but it actually does what you just said

Comment: You are separating your string at each point it finds a backslash `'\'` or when it finds an `'n'` character.  If you want it to delimit your string at a newline character, use `"\n"` as the string literal to pass to `strtok(3)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`strtok() manpage`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok):

> The **delim** argument specifies a set of bytes that delimit the
>   tokens in the parsed string. The caller may specify different strings
>   in delim in successive calls that parse the same string.

So, in your code, `"\\n"` is not a **full string** delimiter. You are just saying to `strtok` that the delimiter is **either** `'\'` (because of the double backspace escaping) **or** `'n'`.

The tokens of your string, `"+ 2 3\\nln 9\\ln 10"` will be:

1. `"+ 2 3"`
2. empty string between `\` and `\` (strtok doesn't present it)
3. empty between `\` and `n` (strtok doesn't present it)
4. `"l"`
5. `" 9"`
6. empty string between `\` and `\` (strtok doesn't present it)
7. `"l"`
8. `" 10"`

In order to perform what you are trying to do, `strtok` is not the best choice. I would probably write my own parsering function

1. Finding `"\\n"` occurrences in original string using `strstr()`
2. Either copying the previous string to some output string or null terminating it in place

Comment: Sorry, my string is "+ 2 3\\nln 9\\ln 10". I have edited my post

Comment: @Avocado This doesn't change the analysis. You will have multiple empty strings instead of one.

Comment: How do I tell `strtok` that the delimiter is `\\n` then?

Comment: @Avocado You can't. It accepts only a set o **single characters** delimiters.

Comment: @Avocado you don't. If you read the linked manpage again, there is no way to provide a delimiter containing more than 1 character. Each character in the string is handled separately. That is why the answer mentions `strstr` as a solution

Comment: What alternatives do I have in order to get my result?

Comment: @Avocado I wrote a little suggestion in the end of my answer

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29788983/split-char-string-with-multi-character-delimiter-in-c  And there is this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34942523/split-string-by-a-substring but ignore the accepted answer which is completely wrong - the other answers may work for you though.

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree with above answer and suggestions by Roberto and Gerhardh.

In case if you are fine with custom implementation of strtok for multiple delimeter, you can use below working solution.

```
char *strtokm(char *str, const char *delim)
{
    static char *tok;
    static char *next;
    char *m;

    if (delim == NULL) return NULL;

    tok = (str) ? str : next;
    if (tok == NULL) return NULL;

    m = strstr(tok, delim);

    if (m) {
        next = m + strlen(delim);
        *m = '\0';
    } else {
        next = NULL;
    }

    return tok;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example.  Theoretically, then, this would be identical to strtok if you used strpbrk instead of strstr.